# If the user presses the enter key, perform the same action as clicking the submit in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I get my enter key to perform the same action and my submit button?

I have my code here, and I would like the form to submit if the user presses submit, or presses the enter button on the keyboard

I have tried using if statements with keycode 13, but nothing is working for me.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    // Add event listeners
    document.getElementById('add-item').addEventListener('click', addItem, false);
    document.querySelector('.todo-list').addEventListener('click', toggleCompleted, false);
    document.querySelector('.todo-list').addEventListener('click', removeItem, false);

    function toggleCompleted(event) {
        console.log('=' + event.target.className);
        if(event.target.className.indexOf('todo-item') < 0) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(event.target.className.indexOf('completed'));
        if(event.target.className.indexOf('completed') > -1) {
            console.log(' ' + event.target.className);
            event.target.className = event.target.className.replace(' completed', '');
            document.getElementById('add-item').value='';
        } else {
            console.log('-' + event.target.className);
            event.target.className += ' completed';         

        }
    }

    function addItem() {
        var list = document.querySelector('ul.todo-list');
        var newItem = document.getElementById('new-item-text').value;
        var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
        newListItem.className = 'todo-item';
        newListItem.innerHTML = newItem + '<span class="remove"></span>';
        list.insertBefore(newListItem, document.querySelector('.todo-new'));
        document.getElementById('new-item-text').value = "";
    }

    function removeItem(event) {
        if(event.target.className.indexOf('remove') < 0) {
            return;
        }
        var el = event.target.parentNode;
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }

    function changeTitle() {
        var title = prompt("change the title");
    }

    function handle(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
    addItem();
    }
    return false;
}

});
```

Comment: If any of the element is in the focus and `enter` key is pressed, it will submit the form.. You do not need to do anything for that!

Comment: @RayonDabre Hmm, it won't submit for me when I press the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the keydown event for this like below

```
   document.onkeydown=function(evt){
   var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
   if(keyCode == 13)
   {
         //your function call here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your set of addEventListeners

```
document.getElementById('add-item').addEventListener('keydown', handle, false);
```